Formula for earliest date with available results n hand inventory
Help on excel earliest date



SKU
qty
receiving date




A
100
01/01/2023


A
200
01/02/2023


A
300
01/03/2023


B
300
01/04/2023


B
200
01/05/2023


B
100
01/06/2023


C
200
01/07/2023


C
300
01/08/2023


C
300
01/09/2023






SKU
ON HAND QTY
earliest date




A
375
?


B
450
?


C
550
?



Column in first table show my receiving details with different qty and date by sku. Columns in second table show my on hand qty.
The column ON HAND QTY is to pick the earliest date at column receiving date with the summation column qty from latest date to earliest date that hit the on hand qty to get that date
Column earliest date is to pick the earliest date at column receiving date, for this SKU.
Expected is (for A,B,C, resp.): 01/02/2023, 01/04/2023, 01/08/2023.
Please help on the formula at column earliest date.

I added the expected values. (which I did forget to add on the staging ground)

Expected is (for A,B,C, resp.): 01/02/2023, 01/04/2023, 01/08/2023. Please assist to revise.

Use [edit], and make the changes

Here is another alternative method to accomplish the desired output using MAP() & SCAN(), this is one single dynamic array formula, one doesn't need to fill down:


• Formula used in cell G2
=MAP(E2:E4,F2:F4,LAMBDA(x,y,
 LET(z,SORT(FILTER(B:C,A:A=x),2,-1),
 XLOOKUP(y,SCAN(,TAKE(z,,1),SUM),DROP(z,,1),,1))))


Or, Using BYROW():
=BYROW(DROP(E.:.F,1),LAMBDA(x,
 LET(z, SORT(FILTER(B.:.C,A.:.A=TAKE(x,,1)),2,-1),
 XLOOKUP(DROP(x,,1),SCAN(,TAKE(z,,1),SUM),DROP(z,,1),"",1))))



Thanks Mayukh Bhattacharya. I have tried a few times by copying both of your formulars and gotten error results. Can you provide your excel file that you work on and email to me? Please kindly advise. My email address - tiangandrew8518@gmail.com

@TIANG程 you can download it from here. ClickLink

Thanks Mayukh Bhattacharya for your file. At on hand qty column, I have changed to other qty and at earliest date column becomes error for all 3 SKU. Please kindly assist. Thanks in advance.

A Most Recent Lookup
In cell H2:
=LET(sdata,A$2:C$10,ss_col,1,sq_col,2,sr_col,3,dSKU,F2,dQTY,G2,
    sSKU,INDEX(sdata,,ss_col),
    f,FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(sdata,sq_col,sr_col),sSKU=dSKU),
    so,SORT(f,2,-1),
    sc,SCAN(0,INDEX(so,,1),SUM),
    r,INDEX(INDEX(so,,2),XMATCH(dQTY,sc,1)),
    r)


Replace the bottom-most r with any other variable to see what it holds.

Depending on the availability of the ETA LAMBDA-s, you might need to replace SUM with something like LAMBDA(rr,r,rr+r).

For each value in column F, it filters the other columns and sorts them descending on the date column. Then it creates a running sum and returns the date of the row where the value is smaller or equal to the given value in column G.




After removing the redundant variables, you would end up with the less readable...

=LET(sdata,A$2:C$10,ss_col,1,sq_col,2,sr_col,3,dSKU,F2,dQTY,G2,
    so,SORT(FILTER(CHOOSECOLS(sdata,sq_col,sr_col),
        INDEX(sdata,,ss_col)=dSKU),2,-1),
    INDEX(INDEX(so,,2),XMATCH(dQTY,SCAN(0,INDEX(so,,1),SUM),1)))


Thanks VBasic2008. I have tried a few times by copying both of your formulars and gotten error results. Can you provide your excel file that you work on and email to me? Please kindly advise. My email address - tiangandrew8518@gmail.com

This requires MS365. Have you tried to replace SUM with LAMBDA(rr,r,rr+r)? Here is the link to the file to download from my Google Drive. Note that you can use the same replacement in Mayukh's solutions.

Thanks VBasic2008 for your file. At column G, I have changed the qty and the return becomes error for all 3 SKU. Please kindly assist. Thanks in advance.

Sorry, I can't help you because I don't know what's going on. I need more information, or send me your file.

My apologies, what I meant is at on hand qty column, I have changed the other qty and at earliest date column becomes error for all 3 SKU. Please kindly assist. Thanks in advance.
